# Running out of memory using LinearGradientBrush

Tags: c#, memory, drawing

I have a program which is drawing lots of lines onto a screen (once per frame, not all in one `Paint()` call), using the `LinearGradientBrush` class.  The endpoints and colors may be different every time.  The code is below:

```
using (Brush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(oldLoc, newLoc, oldColor, newColor))
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(brush))
    {
        g.DrawLine(pen, oldLoc, newLoc);
        pen.Dispose();
    }
    brush.Dispose();
}
GC.Collect();
```

This works for a while but invariably runs out of memory and crashes.  I've tried it with and without the `Dispose()` calls, and with and without the `GC.Collect()`, and it doesn't seem to make a difference.  I would have thought that between the `using` blocks, `Dispose()` and `GC.Collect()`, there would be *something* that clears the memory being allocated, but it doesn't seem to work.

I can't create the brush in advance and reuse it because the endpoints and colors will be different every time.  I've tried saving one `LinearGradientBrush` and just changing its parameters each time I want to use it - this works for the colors, but *not* for the endpoints.  I can apparently *look* at the `Rectangle` property of the brush, but it is `readonly` so it can't be changed.  Is there a better way to draw a gradient line that doesn't depend on knowing where the start and end points are?  In theory, it'd make sense to have a gradient from "start of line" to "end of line" which doesn't need to know where those are when the brush is created.

(Note, this is *not* a duplicate of [c# GDI+, Creating a LinearGradientBrush in a loop (memory leaks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336721/c-sharp-gdi-creating-a-lineargradientbrush-in-a-loop-memory-leaks) because that question has predictable start and end points and colors, and mine need to change every time.)

**Edit:**  Here's the loop-handling code, copied from somewhere, I forget, but it might be relevant:

```
void HandleApplicationIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (IsApplicationIdle())
    {
        Update();
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct NativeMessage
{
    public IntPtr Handle;
    public uint Message;
    public IntPtr WParameter;
    public IntPtr LParameter;
    public uint Time;
    public Point Location;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int PeekMessage(out NativeMessage message, IntPtr window, uint filterMin, uint filterMax, uint remove);

bool IsApplicationIdle()
{
    return PeekMessage(out _, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0) == 0;
}
```

The code above is called from the `Update()` function here.

Comment: This Microsoft Docs article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement indicates that with `using` the `dispose` is called as the object goes out of scope so you shouldn't need explicit calls to `dispose`. see also. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.dispose?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Pen_Dispose which refers to this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged which causes me to wonder if there is an unmanaged object staying around.

Comment: @RichardChambers Yeah, I figured that was probably redundant, but I can't think of what else to do.  If even explicitly calling the GC.Collect doesn't work, I'm kind of at a loss...

Comment: Please provide the source of the entire function or method that this code snippet is being used in. I'm curious about the arguments `oldLoc, newLoc, oldColor, newColor`.

Comment: @RichardChambers They're just `System.Drawing.Point` and `System.Drawing.Color` respectively.  I'm using them in the same way for a number of different things.  The code has no problems when using a `SolidBrush` in the exact same context.  There's not much more I can give as far as surrounding code without just posting the entire program, which is far too large for SE...

Comment: So you are saying that if you replace `LinearGradientBrush` with `SolidBrush ` in the `using` statement it all works fine and you do not run out of memory?

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes, but then of course the line is all one color.  It would just be `new SolidBrush(newColor)`, since `SolidBrush` doesn't care about start/end points and only has 1 color.  I've left that running for hours with no problems.  `LinearGradientBrush` only runs for about a minute before crashing.

Comment: _This works for a while but invariably runs out of memory and crashes_ Doubtful. The Dispose is an error and the GC collect almost always unnecessary. Most likely: There are other iddues.. Simple test: comment all the code you show out and test if the issue is gone..

Comment: *LinearGradientBrush only runs for about a minute before crashing*. It's not that, for sure. To crash an app in *about a minute*, you must have something really, really heavier than that, even if you leaked it. Usually, large Bitmaps. Also, any Bitmap created from the Resources directly. If you don't have an unrecoverable exception somewhere else, that is.

Comment: BTW, there's no reason to write `Brush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(...)`, use `var` or `LinearGradientBrush` instead of `Brush`.

Comment: @TaW - Okay, so the fact that this code works perfectly fine without crashing if `LinearGradientBrush` is replaced with `SolidBrush` with *no other changes*, and the line it crashes on is that `using` statement, that's evidence that the fault is in there somehow.  (Also, if I comment that section out, the program basically doesn't do anything - drawing lines is kind of the whole thing.)

Comment: @Jimi - There is one large Bitmap, 1000x1000, as part of the `PictureBox` I'm drawing in.  I never access the `Bitmap` directly.  I have saved a local `Graphics` reference using `PictureBox.CreateGraphics()` (only called once at the start), and I use that for all my drawing.  (That is the `g` in my code.)  I figured calling `CreateGraphics()` every frame wouldn't exactly be efficient since I'm just using it constantly.  (As for the variable type - fair point but I can't imagine it would matter as far as the crashing issue I'm having.)

Comment: What is the purpose? A screensver or similar animation? Your lines are -non-persistent, which may be just what you want, or maybe not.. How and how often  are those frames triggered? In what range do the points lie? 1000x1000 ? Are they Point or PointF ? Did you try to log them out to see if some (the last ones) are off? Did you actually see the memory usage climb or is this just the erroro message? (These often are quite misleading..) - I can't reproduce: My test runs forever, as expected..

Comment: @TaW Basically yes, it's drawing patterns similar to [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game).  (Normally done with just dots, but adding line drawing methods for other effects.)  All points are within the 1000x1000 range, and they are `Point`, not `PointF`.  I added my loop-handling code in case it helps.

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce. Looking at the example I wonder why you draw them in a non-persistent way, though? They are meant to pile up, not to be cleared while running, right? If so, I wouldn't necessarily use the Paint event but I would draw into the Bitmap. Persistent and easy to save. But whether that is related to your issue, I don't know..

Comment: @TaW - They do pile up, but it's drawing them constantly.  I looked up a number of ways of doing a "game loop" in C#, and this was the simplest.  It's worked perfectly fine for everything else except for this gradient brush.  I don't know if having a reference to the `Bitmap` itself would help, because you'd still need to call `CreateGraphics()` every time before drawing on it, which I have to think would not be efficient.  To test this fairly, it might help to select random points and colors for each call so you're not reusing the same brush every time?  (That's closer to what I'm doing.)

Comment: No, you can cache the Graphics.FromImage(image) object. - Random points and colors is what I use. - Thanks by the way for showing that a Pen can be derived from a LGBrush! Very nice!

Comment: @TaW - Okay, you may be onto something.  In my initialization, I changed `g = pb.CreateGraphics();` to `bmp = new Bitmap(1000,1000); g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp); pb.Image = bmp;`, and in my `Update()` I added a `pb.Invalidate()` at the end to make it actually draw.  (Otherwise it only draws when dragging the window off- and back on-screen.)  I feel like it maybe runs slower, but at least it's not crashing anymore.  Not sure *why* this made the difference, and why the old method *only* had a problem with LGBrush, but this seems to fix it.  If you know why, you could post it as an answer...

Comment: @TaW Actually, scratch that.  It still crashed, just took longer, like 10 minutes rather than under a minute, probably a result of it just running slower.

Comment: __Ha, I got it.!!__. I had a hunch and had asked you to log out the vlaues because in the back of my mind I remembered that GDI+ sometimes can crash when some toxic values are fed into it. Here this will crash (with a silly OOM exception) immediately: `using (Brush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(oldLoc, oldLoc, oldColor, newColor))` - It probably takes a while until the fractal distances get down to 0.. So a simple check will protect it..

Comment: @TaW Ah, so on the (literal) 1 in a million chance chance that oldLoc and newLoc are the same, it crashes?  Let's see... Yes!   Good catch.  That is indeed a very misleading error message.  It now just doesn't draw anything in those cases since it'd only be 1 pixel.  Thanks.